# Java- relative path of text file in main?

Tags: java, file-io, relative-path

I was wondering how to specifiy a relative path name to a text file that is stored in my src folder of a java project.  I would like to store a string with the path of this text file.  For example if I had example.txt located in the src folder of my java project how would I go about finding its relative path?  I am also doing this in my main so I'm having trouble using .getResource().  How would I do this?  Thanks.

My files path is as followed from the properties in eclipse
/MyProject/src/data.txt

I've tried:

String path = "/MyProject/src/data.txt";

But that doesn't work?

Comment: The file must be in the relative path of the java/jar file that will be executed, not of the sources.

Comment: are you using Android? or pure Java?

Comment: can you post your code to see what you did?

Comment: found this post when I encountered an error about "cannot find file specified" then I realized after several attempts that the file name should be in lowercase as in yourfile.fileextension.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, place your text file in the root of the project folder, outside the `/src` and `/bin` folders. It should be now accessible via a relative path directly.

If you want to access a file in src folder, you have to append the `/src/` prefix before the file path/name

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Placing it outside the src folder worked.

Comment: In windows to access a.txt file in src folder use "src/a.txt" not "/src/a.txt"

Answer (score 11):

Use the `src/` prefix before the file path/name.

```
String path = "src/data.txt";
```

Answer (score 3):

The path is relative to the directory you execute the "java" command.e.g.

```
 /opt/projects/myproject>$ java -cp <whatever your classpath is that contains your class files> com.mycompany.mypackage.MyJavaClass
```

in this case the MyJavaClass would find files relative to the directory
    /opt/projects/myproject

There is another way to do this if you  like: you can use load resources, which are found via the classpath mechanism.

```
 getClass().getResource("foo.txt");
```

You can see this posting for more info

[Preferred way of loading resources in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java)

Comment: you can't use "this" in a static method

Comment: getClass is not available in a static context.