# Linking file from same project src into mediaPlayer

Tags: java, eclipse, media-player

I'm trying to play a mp3 but link it from the local folder (Zoo/src/wolfHowl.mp3) so I could export the project and run it on other computers without changing file link 
Thanks for help in advanced

```
    protected void howl() {
        System.out.println("Howl!!!");
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel(); //needed for MediaPlayer();
        String callFile= "File:///C:/Users/Pol/workspace/Zoo/src/wolfHowl.mp3";
        Media  call= new Media(callFile);
        MediaPlayer noiseCreation = new MediaPlayer(call);
        noiseCreation.play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use relative path instead of absolute path. Absolute path is machine dependent.

In your case the right path is "/src/wolfHowl.mp3"

Check the answers to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281428/java-relative-path-of-text-file-in-main).

You can read more on path operations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html).

Comment: Thanks I get  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException though

Comment: you need to append it with file:// i think.

Comment: Or try this "new File("wolfHowl.mp3").getAbsoluteFile()"

Comment: Sorry silly mistake missed the :  still getting Media Exception Media Unavailable,  String callFile= "File:///src/wolfHowl.mp3";

Comment: Final try "new File("wolfHowl.mp3").getAbsoluteFile()" will give you the path of the file. Now you can append the "File://" before the path and that should fix it.