# How to load image using URL from the WEF-INF\image folder to write in a PDF document

Tags: spring-mvc, itext

How to get image URL and used to write in a PDF document.
ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("Image.png");

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preferred way of loading resources in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added the image logo like this in my pdf file

```
    String imgPath = "/img/Kavi025.jpg";
    String absoluteImgPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(imgPath);
    System.out.println(absoluteImgPath);


    Document document= new Document();

PdfWriter writer= PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("d:\\Kavi.pdf"));

document.open();

Image img = Image.getInstance(absoluteImgPath);
img.setAbsolutePosition(100, 200); // x-axis and y-axis position
writer.getDirectContent().addImage(img);
document.close();

    System.out.println("end of method");
```