# How to access images from a resource folder in intelliJ IDEA without having to give entire path name

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, resources

How would I do something like this in intelliJ IDEA

```
File file = new File("C:\Users\Account\Documents\ProjectFolder\ResourceFolder\image");
```

But not have to enter the whole file path in. I'm pretty sure there is a way, and I'm fairly certain it has something to do with adding it to my build path. I know how to do that in Eclipse but not in intelliJ.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use Java resource loading system. This is not depending on your IDE. Once you have [marked a folder as resource folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html) in IntelliJ, it is available in your code as via [resource loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did end up using the resource loader, but I had to convert the java.net.URL it returned into a URI because the URL contained characters such as "%20". And those characters could not be used in the path for a new File. The new URI simply converted those characters into what they really mean, "%20" for instance is actually a space.