# IntelliJ IDEA: Jar doesn't load images when run outside of IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar, jetbrains-ide

I am using JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA IDE. This is what I used to generate the jar file. Running the jar file from the IDE, everything looks fine.

Running the jar from the terminal, none of the images are loaded.

My feeling is, from reading around on this, that this has something to do with the relative paths used for the images... but I can't figure this out. I've tried various different project folder structures suggested on the JetBrains forums and StackOverflow, to no avail. Everything is fine until I run a jar outside of the IDE.

My current project structure:

[image]

How on Earth do I create a jar file that works everywhere?

Comment: have you set your working directory in project settings? (to `res`?) and is the `res` folder being exported into the jar artifact? you can check by going to Build artifact -> Edit and see if it is included in "Output Layout"

Comment: @1blustone Not manually no.. where exactly is this done? Everything works fine except when a jar is run outside of the ide

Comment: assuming you are using the artifact system to build your jar, Build -> Build artifacts -> Edit... -> Output Layout -> the green + button -> Directory Contents, though I am not sure if you would then have to remove the res/ prefix from your paths (i.e. I am not sure if IntelliJ includes the _contents_ or the directory itself.) [It is also possible to set a folder's type to "Resource folder" and I believe it would do this automatically.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314388/how-to-access-images-from-a-resource-folder-in-intellij-idea-without-having-to-g)

Comment: @1blustone I did this and it didn't seem to change anything unfortunately

Comment: I'm trying it out now. resource folders seemed to work for me.

Comment: @1blustone hmm, I can't find a way to mark folders in intellij idea. The link you provided above leads to instructions for webstorm.. but it's not the same on idea. Google search hasn't turned up anything useful so far. Did you mark a folder as a 'resource folder'? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here's what worked for me. I opened the **project structure** window (`Ctrl-Alt-Shift + S`) and went to the Modules tab. From there, I could easily select a folder from the list and click to make it a Resource directory. I was then able to access the resources as `URL`'s with

```
URL imageUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("image.png")
```

No need to use a path to the image, just it's actual **name.ext**

Answer (score 1):

Using IntelliJ's resource folders is probably the right way to go.

Simply right click your `res` folder, go to `Mark Directory As` and select `Resources`.

[image]

Then you can access files in this folder simply by name (without a `res/` prefix.)

Working visual example:

[image]

Comment: The only folder with the other options available is the 'out' folder

Comment: ok I thought that might be it, and changed it to resources but still no dice... I'll restart the project and see

Comment: They are all of the form 'resources/image.png'

Comment: @Totem hmm. Using resource folders, they shouldn't include the directory name - does that work? (Also, does the icon of your res folder match that of my sample `resources` folder?)

Comment: The icon doesn't match, I'll put up a shot of it in the question

Comment: There's a screenshot of the structure above

Comment: @Totem I am not quite sure what that folder icon is and cannot seem to find it anywhere, but I have had that once and that was the exact type of folder that could not be edited. Try recreating your project, I don't think this should usually happen - sorry to not be of much help.

Comment: No worries.. just surprised that there doesn't seem to be any readily available documentation on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Source and Resource roots are handled differently.

All the files from the Resource directories will be always copied to the output path. As suggested in another answer, one of the solutions is to [configure this directory as Resources root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-content-roots.html#project_tool_window). It's the preferred way to get it working.

If you want files from the Source roots to be copied to the output, you have to [specify the patterns](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-compiler-settings.html) for the files that will be copied.

If the project is Maven or Gradle based, these patterns have no effect and IDE will use the rules of the corresponding build system to process the resources.