# Reading file from path in Swing in different environments

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I am creating a Swing application in which some of the icons and images are being loaded from the resource folder within the project.

```
File helpIcon = new File("resources/icon/helpIcon.png");
```

This is working fine in Windows but in Linux this code is giving an error. 
How should I **handle this in different operating systems** (like Windows, Linux, MacOS)?

Comment: try to add / in the begining File helpIcon = new File("/resources/icon/helpIcon.png");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java

Comment: @YoucefLaidani Thanks! so / before resources will take me to src folder or file drive. i am working on E:/project/quizApp/src/com/quizzapp/util/Util.java 
and my resource folder in 
E:/project/quizApp/src/resources?

Comment: @sjc Thanks! i am trying this and let you know.

Comment: In [tag:embedded-resource] click on _learn more…_

Comment: @trashgod Thanks a tons. Finally problem solved by using below snippet.
this.getClass().getResource("/resources/icon/helpIcon.png");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use getClass().getResources("path")