# Getting wrong path resource from a web project java

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, velocity

This is my maven web project structure, and I'm using java 8 + netbeans + jboss eap 6.

```
Project
|__/src
  |__/main
    |__/java
    |__/resources
    | |__/velocity
    |     -template.vm
    |__/webapp
```

Once application is running I'm trying get de resource path /proyect/src/main/resources/velocity/ this way:

```
String path = SomeClass.class.getResource("/" + templateName).getPath();
```

but instead I'm getting a path inside jboss EAP /bin folder like this:

```
C:/Users/MyUser/EAP-6.4.0/bin/content/MyWebApp.war/WEB-INF/classes/velocity/
```

And obviously that path doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you're using the [Apache Velocity Engine](http://velocity.apache.org) you need to configure it to use a [ClasspathResourceLoader](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ClasspathResourceLoader.html).

Then you can simply use the path `/velocity/template.vm` for template processing.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it that way. I'm setting that path into velocity's property `VelocityEngine.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH`.

Comment: You need to load those files as **classpath** resources, not **file** resources because they exist inside the war file and may not be accessible directly in the file system.

Comment: I suppose the instruction `SomeClass.class.getResource()` lookup into classpath, right?

Comment: Yes, but that particular incarnation will yield a resource relative to the package containing `SomeClass`. You should check the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java for a thorough understanding