# Suspected Java Context Loader that uses files that no longer exists

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm writing a test case that loads variables from the resources of my tests and loads them into a Properties object. It checks if there is a type of file that only exists in a Docker container when it is generated by configuration related to the Docker container. Let me be clear: `config.alt.properties` doesn't currently exist in my file system, but it used to and I believe I once ran these tests while it did exist. When I run this within my eclipse environment, I found out via a Debugger that the `ContextClassLoader` pulls the file out of thin air, and loads it with the values that were once in that file, but different from the normal `config.properties` file.

```
props = new Properties();
try (InputStream altInput = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.alt.properties")) {
        if(altInput != null){
            props.load(altInput);
        }
        else{
            LOG.info("Using environment props file");
            InputStream envInput = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
            props.load(envInput);
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Why is this happening? And more importantly, how do I get the ContextClassLoader to forget about this file that isn't here anymore? Here is my project structure:

```
src/main/java: {empty}
src/main/resources: rebel.xml
src/test/java: testClass.Java (where code is from)
src/test/resources: config.properties, log4j2.xml
```

I have tried to use the other methods of resource loading [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java) but all of the other methods lead to the program not finding any files at all including `config.properties`.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: The tests are running using JUnit, I don't know if that matters or not. Here is the JUnit info in the pom.XML

Under dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and under dependencyManagement

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the file does not exist in filesystem, but it seems you only looked for it under the sources directory. But at runtime the program uses resource files under `target` directory (they are copied there at build-time, at "process-resources" phase of default lifecycle), so the only explanation I see, and quick solution is to `mvn clean` (or use "Clean project" feature in Eclipse).

To verify where the file is taken from, right before you get it as stream, try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("‌​config.alt.propertie‌​s")`, log the value, and verify the location it points to.

Comment: mvn clean/reinstall worked to clear it out. I wasn't thinking about the maven aspect of the project and test as much as I should have. Thank you.