# Settings file (settings.json) does not compile along with my program

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I have a program which allows you to edit a couple settings through a "settings.json" file as seen here: https://prnt.sc/jzx8p8

My problem is that this file seems to not compile along with my program, as seen here: https://prnt.sc/jzx8t2
(If you're wondering I have that error message pop up myself: https://prnt.sc/jzx8y2)

I am using IntelliJ's artifact support to compile my program.
Help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: The program runs 100% as it should when I run it through IntelliJ but not when I try to run it through my VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Your json file is not in the classpath and thus is not visible. Move it into resources folder and that should work

Comment: When moving the file to the resources folder the program doesn't run correctly anymore http://prntscr.com/jzxej4 and when it is where it previously was it does run correctly (only though running with IntelliJ)

Answer (score 0):

You are loading it from the working directory as a file, not as a resource from the classpath. Either specify/calculate the full file path so that it works on any system or [change your code to load the resource from the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862115/104891) and move the file into `resources` directory.

Comment: I put the file inside the resources folder and loaded it from there too and again, it works perfectly when running it through IntelliJ but not when I do so on my VPS.
http://prntscr.com/k05l92
http://prntscr.com/k05ld3

Comment: Change to `"/settings.json"`.

Comment: Load it as a stream, not as file, see the linked answer.