# Null pointer exception for file in test/resource

Tags: java, resources

Project Structure

```
/spp-test-automation
  /src
    /main
    /test
      /java
        /com.testing.tool
          Processor.java
      /resources
        processor.json
```

Within `Processor.java` I am trying to grab the contents in my `processor.json` file. However, I am getting a `NullPointerException` and I am not sure why.

For the variable `filepath`, I've tried the values `"src/test/resources/procesoosr.json"`, `"processor.json"`, `"\processor.json"` but I am still getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
```

I have even passing in the absolute path but I get the same error as well.

```
File file = new File("src/test/resources/processor.json");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

I am using Intellij to run these tests and this is what my config looks like. Ignore the red text and I simply renamed the package but the concept is essentially the same

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preferred way of loading resources in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java)

Comment: What have you tried to spot the error? Usually, with current IDEs, you can use a pretty good debugger

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a dot before `src` to  to indicate that you are using the relative path to the project root directory. Otherwise you will search by absolute path.

```
File file = new File("./src/test/resources/processor.json");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = new ReadResourceFileDemo().getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

where fileName="processor.json"

Answer (score 0):

to start: **right click** on the file : choose **Copy path**: there are 3 paths:

1. Absolute  path
2. Content root path
3. Source root path

usually is content root path. After test with those paths

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```